# asustilbar (?): a strange word from the Tractatus de Herbis

Tags: vocabulary, book

There is a following illustration (f. 28r) in the [Tractatus de Herbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_de_Herbis):

[image]

(Here is a [link to an image with high resolution](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/TH_28r.jpg).)
It is written in Wikipedia that "Apparently the artist has confused his animals in this picture, with his drawing of a deer-like creature. "Beavers and musk deers were sought after for castoreum and musk, respectively"" etc.
What I wish to know is what is written near the animal. Apparently it reads "castoreum alio noie asustilbar". I assume that "alio noie" is shortened "alio nomine", "also called". But what is the last word?

Comment: If you look at the scans of the whole MS at www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/record.asp?MSID=7796&CollID=9&NStart=4016 (as I just spent far too long doing), indications of 'by another name' or 'which some people call' are frequent. The other names are a mishmash of Latin, transliterated Greek and Arabic, and what I presume is regional dialect(s) (e.g., folio 62r. gives mus, sorices[?], ratus, and topus [cf. Italian topo] in the caption for a mouse). Since the MS is from Lombardy, perhaps asustilbar is in Lombardic – or something else entirely (Arabic?).

Answer (score 2):

In Isidore (translated Barney et al.) *Etymologies* XX which is the section on cookery, Isidore explains *assus*:

> 22. Roasted (assus), something that is blazing hot, as though the word were *arsus,* burnt.

Two forms exist: ***assus*** and ***assatus.*** I think the first half of the word,  *asust-* is a combination of these two. Apicius, whose book on cookery is famous, uses the verb *asso;* "*assare jecus porcinum.*" (to roast pig’s liver)
Isidore also helps with the second half of the word:::

> 17. *Placentae* are breads made from spelt. Some people call them ***libum***; because they are agreeable (*libere*) and pleasing (*placere*).

(Spelt is a primitive wheat; it has half the number of chromosomes found in cultivated varieties) *Libar*, here as *ilbar,* is likely to be a syncopated back-formation of  from ***Libar***ius, a cook who sold these small *libus* or *libum* birthday cakes.

> Verecunnus libarius hic and Pudens libarius,

which can be roughly translated as 'Verecunnus and Pudens [sell votive bread](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ancient/romans/daily_life_gallery_02.shtml) here'.  (graffiti on the precinct wall of the Temple of Apollo)

**This creates a new problem**. Beaver scent has nothing whatever to do with the musk deer in the picture. And "Blistering hot cup-cakes" is much more suitable as a description of roast chestnuts straight from the fire: *castaneae,* here written *castanee* on the left of the page. A misunderstanding seems to have arisen because because *castanea,* the word for chestnut, is a direct borrowing from Greek. Isidore's Etymologies p.144 provides a specious answer, which connects the chestnut tree to beaver and to musk::

> Latin speakers name the chestnut (castanea)from a Greek term, for the Greeks call it καστάνια, because its paired fruits are hidden in a small sack like testicles, and when they are ejected from it, it is as if they were castrated (*castrare*).

It fits in perfectly with the story of beavers (*Castores*) making themselves valueless to hunters. And explains why this Herbal got the idea that musk deer might resort to the same drastic action.
But there is no connection that I can find between the musk deer and the cryptic "*.Castoreum. alio noie asustilbar*"

Comment: So, you're saying "asus-" is from "assus" and "-(i)lbar" is from "libarius", but what about the "t" in the middle of the word?

Comment: @sumelic, what I've come to think (after spending too much time on this) is these three words have nothing to do with Castor or bollocks, but might possibly have a connection with delicious hot chestnuts, bursting open from the heat.